# Melt multiple boolean columns in a single column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```py
  Windows Linux Mac
0 True    False False
1 False   True  False
2 False   False True
```

I want to combine these three columns in a single column like this

```py
  OS
0 Windows
1 Linux
2 Mac
```

I know that I can write a simple function like this

```py
def aggregate_os(row):
   if row['Windows'] == True:
      return 'Windows'
   if row['Linux'] == True:
      return 'Linux'
   if row['Mac'] == True:
      return 'Mac'
```

which I can call like this

```py
df['OS'] = df.apply(aggregate_os, axis=1)
```

The problem is that my dataset is huge and this solution is too slow. Is there a more efficient way of doing this aggregation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### `idxmax`

```
df.idxmax(1).to_frame('OS')

        OS
0  Windows
1    Linux
2      Mac
```

---

#### `np.select`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {'OS': np.select([*map(df.get, df)], [*df])},
    df.index
)

        OS
0  Windows
1    Linux
2      Mac
```

---

#### `dot`

```
df.dot(df.columns).to_frame('OS')

        OS
0  Windows
1    Linux
2      Mac
```

---

#### `np.where`

Assuming only one `True` per row

```
pd.DataFrame(
   {'OS': df.columns[np.where(df)[1]]},
    df.index
)

        OS
0  Windows
1    Linux
2      Mac
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `boolean indexing` with `stack` and `rename`

```
df_new = df.stack()
df_new[df_new].reset_index(level=1).rename(columns={'level_1':'OS'}).drop(columns=0)
```

**Output**

```
        OS
0  Windows
1    Linux
2      Mac
```