# Melt multiple boolean columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This question is an extension of the one already asked here: [Melt multiple boolean columns in a single column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861364/melt-multiple-boolean-columns-in-a-single-column-in-pandas)

If the data looked like:

```
| System | Windows | Linux | Mac|
| -------- | -------------- |
| Desktop    | True | True | False |
| Laptop | True   | True | False
| Mobile | True   | True | False
| Tablet | False | True | False
```

where '`System`' is `dtype=string` and other columns are `dtype=boolean`. How can I make the final table look like this:

```
| OS | System |
| --- ----- | -------------- |
| Windows| Desktop Laptop Mobile  |
| Linux | Desktop Laptop Mobile Tablet |
| Mac | |
```

where the values in the `System` column are separated by space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is first convert `System` column to `index` and transpose, then use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for matrix multiplication by columns names with space separator:

```
df1 = df.set_index('System').T
df1 = df1.dot(df1.columns + ' ').str.rstrip().rename_axis('OS').reset_index(name='System')
print (df1)
        OS                        System
0  Windows         Desktop Laptop Mobile
1    Linux  Desktop Laptop Mobile Tablet
2      Mac
```

Solution with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) is also possible, only after filtering only `True`s and aggregate `join` is necessary also add removed categories by unique values of columns names (without first):

```
df1 = (df.melt('System', var_name='OS')
         .query("value == True")
         .groupby('OS')['System']
         .agg(' '.join)
         .reindex(df.columns[1:].unique(), fill_value='')
         .rename_axis('OS')
         .reset_index(name='System'))

print (df1)
        OS                        System
0  Windows         Desktop Laptop Mobile
1    Linux  Desktop Laptop Mobile Tablet
2      Mac
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another solution:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['System'],var_name='OS')
df.groupby('OS').agg(lambda x: ' '.join([e for i,e in enumerate(x) if df.loc[x.index[i],'value']]))
```