# Pandas multiple boolean columns to new single column with mapping dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with multiple boolean columns that indicate properties like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [0, 1, 2, 3],
        "non_important_column": ["some", "random", "unneeded", "values"],
        "property_A": [False, True, False, False],
        "property_B": [False, False, False, True],
        "property_C": [False, False, True, False],
    }
)

   id non_important_column  property_A  property_B  property_C
0   0                 some       False       False       False
1   1               random        True       False       False
2   2             unneeded       False       False        True
3   3               values       False        True       False
```

And a mapping dict like so:

```
mapping_dict = {False: "none", "property_A": "foo", "property_B": "bar", "property_C": "baz"}
```

I would like a new `result` column to look like the following:

```
   id non_important_column  property_A  property_B  property_C result
0   0                 some       False       False       False   none
1   1               random        True       False       False    foo
2   2             unneeded       False       False        True    baz
3   3               values       False        True       False    bar
```

Or, in other words,

1. Create a new column called `result`
2. Look at each of the `property_*` columns
3. If all of the `property_*` columns for that row are `False`, return `none` as shown in the `mapping_dict`.
4. If one of the `property_*` columns for that row are `True` (and only one will be), then return the value in the `mapping_dict` for the column name, which is a key inside of the `mapping_dict`.

I have already tried to use the approach similar to the question [Melt multiple boolean columns in a single column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861364/melt-multiple-boolean-columns-in-a-single-column-in-pandas), but this is slightly different. I got weird results from using `idxmax(1).to_frame('result')`.

Comment: Whats happens if multiple `True`s per rows?

Comment: @jezrael There could be multiple `True` statements per row, but they would be from another subset of the data. For example, there might be another set of columns called `someother_property_*` that I would do the same operation to separately. So there could be one `True` in `property_A`, and another `True` in `someother_property_B`, but they would not collide. AFAIK there would be no case where there would be multiple `True` statements in one subset of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only one or no Trues values per rows use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html), then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and last replace only `False`s rows by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df1 = df.filter(like='property_')
df['result'] = (df1.idxmax(axis=1).map(mapping_dict)
                    .where(df1.any(axis=1), mapping_dict[False]))
print (df)
   id non_important_column  property_A  property_B  property_C result
0   0                 some       False       False       False   none
1   1               random        True       False       False    foo
2   2             unneeded       False       False        True    baz
3   3               values       False        True       False    bar
```

Comment: In the end I used this approach. Thank you @jezrael!

Answer (score 1):

```
res = []
for index, row in df[["property_A","property_B","property_C"]].iterrows():
    if sum(row) == 1:
        val = row[row == True].index 
        res.append(mapping_dict[val[0]])
    else:
        res.append(mapping_dict[False])

df['result'] = res
df

    id  non_important_column    property_A  property_B  property_C  result
0   0   some     False  False   False   none
1   1   random   True   False   False   foo
2   2   unneeded False  False   True    baz
3   3   values   False  True    False   bar
```

If you have multiple True in a row you can handle by adding and elif case

Comment: Will, thank you for this. I actually used this approach in another portion of my data analysis, so it was still very useful!

Comment: @ScottCrooks Ok thanks, so if it was useful can you vote up my answer?

Comment: Yes, I will do that.